# How does inversion look like for the Fourier transform of a measure?

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure, say, on the circle $\mathbb{T} = \mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$. We get the coefficients $C(\mu)(n) = \int_\mathbb{T} e^{-2 \pi i n  x} d\mu(x)$. How does one go back to the measure if they have the coefficients?

Comment: let $f(x) = \int_0^x d\mu(t) = \mu([0,x])$ so that $d\mu(x) = f'(x)dx$ ( <--distributional or Radon-Nikodym derivative here) and $\int_0^1 f(x) e^{-2i \pi n x}dx = \frac{f(1)-f(0)}{-2i \pi n}+ \frac1{2i \pi n}\int_0^1 f'(x) e^{-2i \pi n x}dx  = \frac{C(\mu)(n)}{2i \pi n}$ i.e. $ \mu([0,x]) = f(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{C(\mu)(n)}{2i \pi n} e^{2i \pi n x}$

Comment: How would that work if, say, we are dealing with the Haar measure on a locally compact abelian group instead?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to work with the integral over $[0,2\pi]$ as opposed to over $[0,1]$ because I'm used to it. You can change variables in order to view $\mu$ over $[0,2\pi]$, and then you're considering
$$
            C_{\mu}(n) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{-in\theta}d\mu(\theta).
$$

The Poisson kernel is
$$
              P(r,\theta)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{1-r^2}{1-2r\cos(\theta)+r^2}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}r^{|n|}e^{in\theta}.
$$
Therefore,
$$
     \int_{0}^{2\pi}P(r,\theta-\theta')d\mu(\theta')
    = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}r^{|n|}C_{\mu}(n)e^{in\theta}.
$$
If $J_{(a,b)} = \{ e^{i\theta} : a < \theta < b \}$ and $J_{[a,b]}=\{ e^{i\theta} : a \le \theta \le b \}$, then
\begin{align}
             &\lim_{r\uparrow 1}\int_{a}^{b}\left(\int_{0}^{2\pi}P(r,\theta-\theta')d\mu(\theta')\right)d\theta
    \\
   &= \lim_{r\uparrow 1}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(\int_{a}^{b}P(r,\theta-\theta')d\theta\right)d\mu(\theta')\\
   &= \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2}\left[\chi_{(a,b)}(\theta')+\chi_{[a,b]}(\theta')\right]d\mu(\theta')\\
  &= \frac{1}{2}\mu J_{(a,b)}+\frac{1}{2}\mu J_{[a,b]}.
\end{align}
From that, you can obtain the $\mu$ measure of any open, closed or half-open continuous arc of the circle, which is enough to uniquely determine any Borel measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{T}$.